Why does roblox studio walk wrong through the table
I am making a game right now in roblox, and need to make gamepass store, however when my loop goes through it (its a table in table), it goes out of order
Example code with the tables in table
a = {
    ["5robux"] = {
        value = 10,
        name = "21"
    },
    ["10robux"] = {
        value = 13,
        name = "31"
    },
    ["15robux"] = {
        value = 20,
        name = "41"
    },
    ["20robux"] = {
        value = 25,
        name = "64"
    },
    ["61robux"] = {
        value = 25,
        name = "64"
    },
    ["50robux"] = {
        value = 3,
        name = "64"
    }


}
for i, v in pairs(a) do
    print(i, v)
end

Output:
5robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
50robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
61robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
20robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
15robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
10robux  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30

As you see, it firstly goes to the first element, then to the last and so on
Also tried removing the brackets [], got another output which is still incorrect
Output:
robux15  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
robux5  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
robux50  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
robux61  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
robux10  ▶ {...}  -  Server - Script:30
robux20  ▶ {...} 

How can i fix it, and whats wrong?
Tried changing the loop, but still wrong output

Dictionaries in Lua aren't in order, only arrays are. If you want to be able to iterate over it in the correct order try something like
a = {
    {
        key = "5robux",
        value = 10,
        name = "21"
    },
    {
        key = "10robux",
        value = 13,
        name = "31"
    },
    {
        key = "15robux",
        value = 20,
        name = "41"
    },
}
for i, v in ipairs(a) do
    print(i, v.key)
end

Which will output this
1   5robux
2   10robux
3   15robux


Thank you so much! It worked. Didnt know there wasnt any order in dictionaries

Nitpick: There aren't separate "array" and "dictionary" types in Lua. It's all tables; pairs doesn't guarantee any order.

Syntactically yeah there is no different to an array vs a dictionary, but internally there is a difference. All integer keys get stored in the array part, any other key is stored in the hash array. (There is a bit more that goes on under the hood, if over 50% of the integer keys are empty it goes into the hash part

Removed the keys from the table (instead of 5robux just the table), and it worked!
Example:
a = {
    {
        key = "5robux",
        value = 10,
        name = "21"
    },
    {
        key = "10robux",
        value = 13,
        name = "31"
    },
    {
        key = "15robux",
        value = 20,
        name = "41"
    },
}

Thanks to gsck
